# How to protect my 12 V, 10 A circuit? I am using a fuse but it failed

Tags: current-limiting, over-voltage-protection

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZtcWc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My first question and first project.

I have a circuit. It works on 12 volt & 10 amp circuit. I need to protect it from OVER CURRENT & OVER VOLTS. I am using fuse of 10 A rating.

It is suppose to be plugged in car battery to operate.

I thought that fuse is enough. But for some reason, a friend connected it with the jump start battery kit (not regular SLA battery) and it blew up the first component (12V to 5V step down) in line. I thought that it is just a malfunction and I replaced component and again he attached and it blew again.

I think car jump start battery kit is designed to provide high current/voltage in start and that fried my component and fuse is not protecting.

Do you think fuse can help in both amp and current?

Comment: First of all, what is your project? Can you provide a schematic? Does it require 10A to operate? What is your voltage and current rating on the fuse?

Comment: "both amp and current" are the same thing. And a 10A fuse will probably take 20A briefly before blowing, and do NOTHING about overvoltage. Also we don't know what component you keep blowing...

Comment: The circuit is arudino with LED. The component that blew was Step Down converter from 12V to 5V. Its rating is 10A. The circuit uses maximum 6A in use but I have made my circuit to work til 10A.

Comment: @BrianDrummond how can i protect from high volts ?

Comment: If my understanding is correct. It is not over current (amp) that fried the step down. Because circuit only draw current that is needed. And in start the LED panel only uses very small current until all LEDs start to turn on. It must be over volt. What do you think?

Comment: A thermal fuse doesn't break because of current, it breaks because of the actual temperature of whatever it's attached to. If your device is rated to break at a certain current, that's just a "fuse", not a "thermal fuse".

Comment: A fuse or circuit breaker's purpose is not to protect the equipment. It is to cut power under fault conditions to prevent fire, basically. You have to design circuits that can withstand any normal operating conditions, including overvoltage, if you want them to keep working afterwards.

Comment: An arduino with an LED? And this uses 6A and up to 10?!?! Are you sure? Can you edit your question and use the schematic editor on the site so we can see what is going on?

Comment: @MCG YES I have used amp meter to see how much amp it is using. It uses 6A maximum. But my all components are up-to 10A supported. It does not mean that it needs 10A. It uses max 6A. I hope it explains.

Comment: No... still need a schematic so we know exactly what is happening. Then we can help diagnose where your problem is

Comment: @MCG I just made my first schematic :-) I apologize for bad job. I am learning how to build schematics. Hopefully this will give an idea.

Comment: Thermal fuses are used to protect against over-temperature failures. They need to be placed in a location that will get hot when the failure occurs. They may or may not blow when the current gets high, but that is not their purpose. If you want to protect against over-current, you would use a standard fuse.

Comment: Most DC/DC converters have built-in over current protection, and most can handle much more than 12V. Which converter are you using?

Comment: @mkeith I am using standard fuse. I dont recall I mentioned that I am using thermal fuse. I am using [10A fuse](https://www.jaycar.com.au/10a-m205-quick-blow-fuse/p/SF2168)

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am using DC/DC converter which can take 12V to 24V and has 10A rating.

Comment: "I am using DC/DC converter which can take 12V to 24V and has 10A rating" - but you won't tell us which one it is, so we can't check the specs or determine what internal protections it might have. I'm guessing it has a current limit and the jump starter isn't putting out more than 24V, so it's blowing up for some _other_ reason.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am sorry I do not know much about the device. Please checkout this device [DC 12V/24V to 5V](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/DC-DC-Voltage-Converter-Regulator-Step-Down-Step-Up-Adapter-Car-Power-Module-/292196400190?var=&hash=item4408433c3e:m:m2MQ0XaSnO4KvZAOJDSNLgA)

Comment: The phrase "thermal fuse" is right there in your main question.

Comment: Is it just me struggling to see 6A coming from this circuit?

Comment: @ThePhoton and others: "Thermal fuse" is my fault. I edited the question title and post to remove the OP's "blow-up fuse" terminology. Can someone fix it with a better term?

Comment: @Transistor, I changed it to "fuse".

Comment: @Sallu Did your circuit work before it was connected to the "car start battery kit", or was that the first time it was tested?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, It works fine on regular battery. Normal car battery it works fine.

Comment: I should have checked the edit history. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thermal breaker or "normal" fuse is not very good protection for a switching power supply.  They can take tens or hundreds of milliseconds to react, but the power supply components can be damaged in microseconds.

Linear Technology makes several input protection controller chips that include drive for an electronic circuit breaker that can respond in microseconds, overvoltage and undervoltage shutdown, and reverse polarity protection.  I've used them in MIL projects with very harsh electrical environments and transients.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. There are so many products at their website in this category [Surge Stopper, Overvoltage & Overcurrent Protection](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Surge_Stopper,_Overvoltage_*_Overcurrent_Protection) which one do you recommend?

Comment: @Sallu -- product recs aren't something a Stack handles well, but I'd suspect your biggest issue will be package size, so I'd start with what's available in SO-16...